# Postgresql Table Partitioning Django Project

Tags: django, postgresql, partitioning

I have a Django 1.7 project that uses Postgres 9.3. I have a table that will have rather high volume. The table will have anywhere from 13million to 40million new rows a month.

I would like to know what the best way to incorporate Postgres table partitioning with Django?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you use [*inheritance*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html), and then only connect the parent table to your *Django* model, the partitions should be entirely transparent to *Django*. That is, a `SELECT` on the parent table will cascade down to the partitions, unless the `ONLY` keyword is explicitly used (where applicable).

Note that partitioning does add complexity in terms of needing to implement a programmatic method of determining when new partitions need to be created, and then creating them -- or doing this manually at certain intervals. Depending on your exact data and business logic, it is quite likely you may also need to implement *triggers* and *rules* to determine which partition to, say, `INSERT` something into (since you wouldn't want to `INSERT` into the parent table). These, too, should be abstracted from *Django*, however.

I have found that, depending on the exact circumstances, this may need to be done with your main apps shutdown, lest the new partition creation cause a deadlock.

Also worth considering is whether you need true partitions which get created over time, or if an inheritance model of, say, tables `foo` and `foo_archive` would suffice, where `foo_archive` inherits from `foo`, and periodically something (e.g. a script) moves older data into `foo_archive` to keep `foo` smaller.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [Architect](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect) application for [Postgresql Table Partitioning Django Project](http://architect.readthedocs.org/features/partition/postgresql.html)

> PostgreSQL’s partitioning implementation in Architect is done purely
>   at the database level. That means that Architect creates several
>   triggers and functions and inserts them directly into the database, so
>   even if you issue direct insert statement from database console and
>   not from the ORM, everything will work as expected and record will be
>   inserted into the correct partition, if partition doesn’t exist, it
>   will be created for you automatically. Also partitions may be created
>   in any order and not only from lower to higher.

It's new version of old [Django DB Parti application](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-parti)

Comment: So this is true but it doesn't look like it creates the table as partitioned, so adding indexes doesn't seem to flow into the child tables.

Comment: Update, Postgres supports partitioning well in version 12, so you should update to that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using newer version of PostgreSQL, you can try this

https://github.com/chaitin/django-pg-timepart

> A Django extension that implements PostgreSQL tables for partitioning and management based on dates.