# How to integrate postgresql 10/11 declarative table partitioning (i.e. PARTITION BY clause) in a Django model?

Tags: django, postgresql, database-partitioning

PostgreSQL 10 introduces [declarative table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) with the `PARTITION BY` clause, and I would like to use it to a Django model.

In principle all what I would need to do is introduce the `PARTITION BY` clause at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement that the Django ORM creates.

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (
    city_id         int not null,
    logdate         date not null,
    peaktemp        int,
    unitsales       int
) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

Is it possible to insert this clause into the model? I thought that maybe there is a way to somehow append custom SQL to the query that the ORM generates, e.g. using the Meta:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        append = "PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate)"
```

As far as I am concern the above is not possible. I have also look into the [architect](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect) library, but it does not use the new PARTITION BY clause. Instead, it uses inheritance and triggers so the code does not suggest any way in which I could append the clause (neither it does for other databases, e.g. MySQL).

I have also though of customizing the migrations, by adding an `ALTER TABLE...` operation, e.g.:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
        "ALTER TABLE measurement PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate)",
    ),
]
```

Unfortunately, the above (or similar) doesn't seem to be supported in PostgreSQL [`ALTER TABLE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-altertable.html)(at least not yet).

A final idea would be to retrieve the `CREATE TABLE` statement that the Django model generates, before sending the query, e.g. `sql = Measurement.get_statement()` where `Measurement` is the model. Then, I could append the `PARTITION BY` clause, and send the query directly. I couldn't find any method that returns the statement. I went through the [Django `create_model` code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L241) and the sql is [generated and directly send to the database](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/schema.py#L292-L301), so it would not be easy to extract the statement from there.

Does anybody has a clue how this could be achieved in a way in which I can I still use the benefits of the Django ORM?

Comment: Did you see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351679/2890724  ?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda, yes, I did, i wrote about architect in the question, `architect` does not use `PARTITION BY` for partitions, but inheritance with combination wit triggers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I did it with Window and `partition_by` within the Window class.

Comment: which `Window` class? afaik, there is not such class in Django. Could you be more specific? Maybe you can refer me to which part of my question is not clear.

Comment: @toto_tico I'm pretty sure @billy-ferguson was referring to the [`Window` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) used to performing SQL windowing that happens to have a `partition_by` kwarg. That's not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An approach I suggest trying is to use a SQL capturing schema editor to collect the SQL necessary to perform the `create_model`. That's what powers [the `sqlmigrate` feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) by the way.

```
from django.db.migrations import CreateModel

class CreatePartitionedModel(CreateModel):
    def __init__(self, name, fields, partition_sql, **kwargs):
        self.partition_sql = partition_sql
        super().__init__(name, fields, **kwargs)

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        collector = type(schema_editor)(
            schema_editor.connection, collect_sql=True, atomic=False
        )
        with collector:
            super().database_forwards(
                app_label, collector, from_state, to_state
            )
        collected_sql = collector.collected_sql
        schema_editor.deferred_sql.extend(
            collector.deferred_sql
        )

        model = to_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.name)
        create_table = 'CREATE TABLE %s' % schema_editor.quote_name(
            model._meta.db_table
        )
        for sql in collected_sql:
            if str(sql).startswith(create_table):
                sql = '%s PARTITION BY %s' % (sql.rstrip(';'), self.partition_sql)
            schema_editor.execute(sql)
```

From that point you should simply have to replace your `makemigrations` auto-generated `CreateModel` with a `CreatePartitionedModel` operation and make sure to specify `partition_sql='RANGE (logdate)'`.

Comment: Thanks - FYI I had to made 2 changes. 1. Remove the self parameter passed to ```super().__init__() ```
2. I got ```AttributeError: 'DatabaseSchemaEditor' object has no attribute 'deferred_sql'``` as this was only added in the ```__enter__```  method. Fix by adding  ```with collector:``` before ```super().database_forwards```

Comment: @DaveLawrence thanks I'll incorporate these adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for such inspiration. by the way with postgresql 12 when you use PARTITION RANGE (logdate), logdate should be part of the primary key, otherwize it's not accepted.

Comment: In my situation, if I want to include the datefield used for the RANGE in the primary key, I need a primary key composed of 2 fields. Such situation is not managed by django (still under development), so the only solution I've found is to create my model in SQL and declare it as not managed in my models. Thanks anyway for the example, I've learned something new.